# Storing SQL Server array in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to run a `SELECT` statement on this SQL Server database (and store the rows as variables, in an associative array so I can insert into a mysql database), and getting a few errors I don't understand.

First of all

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    id, accountType, displayName, uid, parentOrg
FROM 
    censored.datatable
```

I've only had experience with MySQL, so I don't see what is wrong with the select above.

Second issue(s)... The select statement above is passed to this function below as $query.

```
function query($query){
    $data = mssql_init($query, $this->getCon());
    $var = array('id','accountType','displayName','uid','parentOrganization_id');
    $row = array();
    do {
        mssql_execute($data);
        //$data->mssql_bind($row['id'], $row['accountType'], $row['displayName'], $row['uid'],
       // $row['parentOrganization_id']);
        mssql_bind($data ,'@id', $var['id'], SQLFLT8, false, 10);
        mssql_bind($data ,'@accountType', $var['accountType'], SQLVARCHAR, false, 10);
        mssql_bind($data ,'@displayName', $var['displayName'], SQLVARCHAR, false, 10);
        mssql_bind($data ,'@uid', $var['uid'], SQLFLT8, false, 10);
        mssql_bind($data ,'@parentOrganization_id', $var['parentOrganization_id'], SQLFLT8, false, 10);
        while ($row = mssql_fetch_object($data)){
            array_push($row, [$row['id'], $row['accountType'], $row['displayName'], $row['uid'],
                $row['parentOrganization_id']]);
        }
    }while ( mssql_next_result($data) );
    return $row;
}
```

This is supposed to be storing each row of the result set into the associative array. here's all the errors this query function comes back with

> Warning: mssql_execute(): stored procedure execution failed in C:\Users\jmurdock\Report\HQDevBox.php on line 51[mssql_execute()]
>   Warning: mssql_bind(): Unable to set parameter in C:\Users\jmurdock\Report\HQDevBox.php on line 58[mssql_bind, error appears for all mssql_binds... lines 54-58]
>   Warning: mssql_fetch_object(): supplied resource is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in C:\Users\jmurdock\Report\HQDevBox.php on line 59
>   Warning: mssql_next_result(): supplied resource is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in C:\Users\jmurdock\Report\HQDevBox.php on line 63[mssql_next_result]

I have a feeling a for loop would be better.. Any help would be appreciated. The connection is valid, I'm 95% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pretty sure you're supposed to make your `mssql_bind()` calls *before* `mssql_execute()`.
2. The 6th parameter to `mssql_bind()` is a boolean, the 7th is an integer. [Ref](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php)
3. `$var` is not an associative array, but you're referring to it like one.